# Android External Storage: What is the difference?

Tags: android, storage

I would like to find the path for the external storage, so I use the following:

```
File[] dirs = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this, null);
```

In returned I get the Array of:

```
dir[0] = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.proj/files/"
dir[1] = "/storage/12FE-350D/Android/data/com.example.proj/files/"
```

What is the difference between those two items ?
And if I want to store images, which one is better to be used ?

Thanks for some highlights.